# Required field validator for a textbox in MVC depend on a dynamically generated drop down list

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-validation

I'm generating some controls with the help of a for-each loop. I would like to validate the textbox depend on the answer of the dropdown. For some questions, validator should be enabled if the selected item in dropdown is "yes" and for some questions validator should be enabled if the answer from the dropdown is "no". At the moment it fires for both because I don't how to control it as the controls are dynamically generated

**View**

```
        @for (int a = 0; a < Model.ServiceQaVisits.Count(); a++)
        {
            if (Model.ServiceQaQuestions[a].sqqQuestionID == Model.ServiceQaVisits[a].sqvQuestionID)
            {
                <div>
                    @Html.DisplayTextFor(m => m.ServiceQaVisits[a].sqvQuestionID)
                    @Html.DisplayTextFor(m => m.ServiceQaQuestions[a].sqqQuestion)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ServiceQaVisits[a].sqvQAID)
                    @if (Model.ServiceQaQuestions[a].sqqQuestionTypeID == 1)
                    {

                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ServiceQaVisits[a].sqvAnswer)
                    }
                    else if (Model.ServiceQaQuestions[a].sqqQuestionTypeID == 2)
                    {
                        List<string> lista = new List<string>() { "Yes", "No" };
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ServiceQaVisits[a].sqvAnswer, new SelectList(lista), "Select Answer")
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        List<string> listb = new List<string>() { "Yes", "No", "N/A" };
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ServiceQaVisits[a].sqvAnswer, new SelectList(listb), "Select Answer")
                    }
                    @if (Model.ServiceQaQuestions[a].sqqNegativeAnswer != null)
                    {
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ServiceQaVisits[a].sqvComment)
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ServiceQaVisits[a].sqvComment,"", new {@class = "text-danger"});
                    }


                </div>
            }

        }
```

**Model**

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter the reason")]
    public string sqvComment { get; set; }
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: better to write the validation in client side , or else allow the request to pass to the controller and there you can write a filter to do this task

Comment: Its not clear what you mean by _Sometimes the textbox needs to be validated if the answer from the dropdown is "Yes" and sometimes needs to be validated if the answer is "No"._

Comment: @StephenMuecke I edited the question. Basically the validation should be enabled depend on the answer from dropdown list. Whether its is a yes or a no

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV do you have an example. I just can't get my head around it.

Comment: Its still not clear when you want it to be validated. Is it required if the selected option is Yes, or is it required if the selected option is No?

Comment: @StephenMuecke for example Q1: if the user selects "yes" validator should be enabled. Q2: If the user answers "no" validation should be enabled. Hope this makes sense

Comment: What about Q3, and Q4 and Q5? (what is the condition?)

Comment: @StephenMuecke in the table structure I have a column defining which answer from the dropdown is considered as a negative answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183176/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-kmr).

Answer (score 1):

There are two parts to the solution, as validation should happen both on server and on client.

On the server, you should use `[CustomValidation]` attribute on your `sqvComment` property. For example, your validation method can be

```
public static ValidationResult ValidateSqvComment(string value, ValidationContext context)
{
     ValidationResult result = ValidationResult.Success;
     MyModel model =  context.ObjectInstance as MyModel;
     if (model.sqvAnswer == "Yes" && String.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
     {
         result = new ValidationResult("sqvComment is required");
     }
     return result;
}
```

and decorate your property with

```
[CustomValidation(typeof(MyModel), nameof(MyModel.ValidateSqvComment))]
public string sqvComment { get; set; }
```

On the client things are more complicated. What MVC does, if you look at the generated source, is add special properties to the `input` elements, that it then parses in client side to add the jQuery validation. in particular, it adds a `data-val="true"` to enable validation, and then `data-val-*=...`, depending on the type of validation. you need to dynamically add these attributes, and then call the parsing function to parse them. In your case, you need to add the `data-val-required="sqvComment is required"` attribute to your `sqvComment` field (through the `htmlAttribute` argument of the `Html.TextBoxFor()` method), and then set the value of `data-val` to `true` only if the answer to the drop-down is "Yes" (or whatever your logic is), using the `onchange` event in client code. Then, you need to clear the validation that jQuery already picked up, and recreate it:

```
jqForm.removeData("unobtrusiveValidation");
jqForm.removeData("validator");
$.validator.unobtrusive.parse(formId);
```

where `jqForm` is a jQuery object with your form, and `formId` is a selector to the form.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Could you please tell me, the server side code goes in the controller? and this [CustomValidation(typeof(MyModel), nameof(MyModel.ValidateSqvComment))]
public string sqvComment { get; set; } goes in the metaData class?

Comment: @KMR The validation method should go in your model, because the model is the atomic business logic unit. It is responsible for validating itself. You should check the validation by calling `ModelState.IsValid()` in your controller. The property with the attribute indeed goes to the metadata class, linked with the `[MetadataType]` attribute to your model class (assuming it is generated).

Comment: @KMR If my answer helped you, I'll appreciate if you accept it :)